# using regular expression classes in c++

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

Each time that I try to initialize a regular expression by a pattern which contains a class-expression (something surrounded by `[` and `]`) my program ends throwing a `regex_error`.
For definiteness, this could be the program:

```
// main.cpp
#include <regex>
int main(){
    std::regex r("[ab]*"); 
}
```

I managed to build the program successfully using either

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main.exe
```

(I have `gcc version 4.8.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9)`)
or

```
clang++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main.exe
```

(with `Debian clang version 3.2-7ubuntu1 (tags/RELEASE_32/final) (based on LLVM 3.2)`)
However, in both cases executing `main.exe` gives me:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
what():  regex_error
```

The curiousity is that the whole thing does work for patterns which do not include class-brackets (`[` and  `]`) as, e.g., `std::regex r("ab*")`.
What could be the problem? 
Thanks already!

---

Update:
Problem worked around in two ways with help of the comments of (1) [ecatmur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/567292/ecatmur) and (2) [Cubbi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/273767/cubbi).
(1) Either, you can install boost and use [`boost::regex`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) (after making sure that the boost root directory is in your include path, then using `#include <boost/regex.hpp>`) and linking the `boost_regex` library (for me this means compiling like this: `g++ -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ -lboost_regex main.cpp -o main.exe`).
(2) Or, you can install [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org/) and use `clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ main.cpp -o main.exe`
Thx for the help!

Comment: Apparently, `<regex>` will work in gcc 4.9; if you can't wait till that's released, maybe use boost?

Comment: I have seen the suggested post... That's why I tried clang. I read somewhere it works fine. Actually , in the very same post [tunnuz](http://stackoverflow.com/users/25418/tunnuz) mentions that his code works with LLVM - though there are no brackets in his pattern.

Comment: IIRC LLVM on Debian uses libstdc++ so you're using the same regex implementation, though.

Comment: Does this mean that there is no working std::regex implementation available for my system (linux / ubuntu) right now?

Comment: Depends how much work you're willing to go to; the gcc 4.9 implementation is in SVN trunk so you could use that.  Otherwise just use boost.regex (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: You can also install LLVM libc++ on Linux if you'd like, from http://libcxx.llvm.org/ - your example would work then: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bfbc3755ba96f244  , but boost is the safer bet.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have tried both solutions -- both work for all examples I tested. I'll add them to my original post.